# How should I calculate the $n$th derivative of $f(x)=x^x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What would be the $n$th derivative of

$ f (x) = x ^ x$

I have reached the fifth derivative, very long indeed but I see no pattern that will help me find a general expression.

\begin{align*}
\frac{df}{dx} &= x^x(1+\ln(x))\\
\frac{d^2f}{dx^2} &= x^x\left(\frac{1}{x}+1+2\ln(x)+\ln(x)^2\right)\\
\frac{d^3f}{dx^3} &= x^x\left( \frac{-1}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x} + \ln(x)^3 + 3 \ln(x)^2 + \frac{3\ln(x)}{x} + 3\ln(x) + 1 \right)\\
\frac{d^4f}{dx^4} &= x^x\left( \frac{2}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{4\ln(x)}{x^2}+\frac{6}{x}+\ln(x)^4+4\ln(x)^3\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\left.+\frac{6\ln(x)^2}{x}+6\ln(x)^2+\frac{12\ln(x)}{x}+4\ln(x)+1 \right)\\
\frac{d^5f}{dx^5} &= x^x\left( \frac{-6}{x^4}+\frac{10\ln(x)}{x^3}+\frac{5}{x^2}-\frac{10\ln(x)^2}{x^2}+\frac{10}{x}+\ln(x)^5+5\ln(x)^4\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\left.+\frac{10\ln(x)^3}{x}+10\ln(x)^3+\frac{30\ln(x)^2}{x}+10\ln(x)^2+\frac{30\ln(x)}{x}+5\ln(x)+1 \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you show us what you have achieved?

Answer (score 13):

This approach  follows an example (p. 139) of *[Advanced Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9027703809)* by L. Comtet. The elaboration here differs in minor aspects and is sometimes more detailed which was helpful to verify the example.

> **Taylor series (part one):**
>
> The idea for this formula of the $n$-th derivative of $x^x$ with $x>0$ is based upon a clever Taylor series expansion.

Recall a Taylor series expansion of a function $f(t)$ at a point $x$ is, assuming $f$ is sufficiently often differentiable
\begin{align*}
f(t)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{D_x^jf(x)}{j!}(t-x)^j
\end{align*}

Here we use the differential operator $D_x^j:=\frac{d^j}{dx^j}$ and we will also use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series.

Since 
\begin{align*}
f(t+x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty D_x^jf(x)\frac{t^j}{j!}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

we can describe the $n$-th derivative of a function $f$ at a point $x$ as
\begin{align*}
D_x^nf(x)=n![t^n]f(t+x)\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> Setting $f(x)=x^x, x>0$ we start according to the LHS of (1) with 
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x+t)=(x+t)^{x+t}
> \end{align*}
>   and obtain with some elementary transformations and series expansion of the exponential function
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x+t)&=(x+t)^{x+t}\\
> &=\exp({(x+t)\ln(x+t)})\\
> &=\exp\left({(x+t)\left(\ln(x)+\ln\left(1+\frac{t}{x}\right)\right)}\right)\\
> &=x^x\exp\left({t\ln(x)}\right)\exp\left({x\left(1+\frac{t}{x}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{t}{x}\right)}\right)\\
> &=x^x\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{\left(t\ln(x)\right)^i}{i!}\right)
> \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\left(1+\frac{t}{x}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{t}{x}\right)\right)^j}{j!}x^j\right)\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

In order to calculate the Taylor series expansion of the RHS of (1) we need to expand (3) in powers of $t$. We use the Ansatz
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{j!}\left(\left(1+\frac{t}{x}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{t}{x}\right)\right)^j
=\sum_{k=j}^\infty b_{k,j}\frac{\left(\frac{t}{x}\right)^k}{k!}\qquad\text{and}\qquad b_{0,0}=1
\end{align*}
Note that since the series expansion of the logarithm has no constant term we start the series expansion with  $\left(\frac{t}{x}\right)^j$, resp. with index $k=j$.

> **Recurrence relation: $b_{k,j}$**
>
> In order to determine $b_{k,j}$ we develop a recurrence relation. We set
>   \begin{align*}
> B_j(z):=\frac{1}{j!}\left(\left(1+z)\ln(1+z\right)\right)^j=\sum_{k=j}^\infty b_{k,j}\frac{z^k}{k!}\quad\qquad (j\geq 0)\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

Differentiating the LHS gives
\begin{align*}
D_zB_j(z)&=\frac{1}{(j-1)!}\left((1+z)\ln(1+z)^{j-1}\right)(1+\ln(1+z))\\
&=B_{j-1}(z)+\frac{j}{1+z}B_j(z)
\end{align*}

Differentiating the RHS gives
\begin{align*}
D_zB_j(z)=\sum_{k=j}^\infty b_{k,j}\frac{z^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}
\end{align*}

Equating both sides and multiplying with $1+z$ gives
\begin{align*}
(1+z)\sum_{k=j}^\infty b_{k,j}\frac{z^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}&=(1+z)B_{j-1}(z)+jB_j(z)\\
&=(1+z)\sum_{k=j-1}^\infty b_{k,j-1}\frac{z^{k}}{k!}+j\sum_{k=j}^\infty b_{k,j}\frac{z^{k}}{k!}
\end{align*}
Comparing coefficients by calculating $\frac{1}{n!}[z^n]$ gives
\begin{align*}
b_{n+1,j}+nb_{n,j}=b_{n,j-1}+nb_{n-1,j-1}+jb_{n,j}
\end{align*}

> Collecting equal terms we finally get
>   \begin{align*}
> b_{n+1,j}=(j-n)b_{n,j}+b_{n,j-1}+nb_{n-1,j-1}\qquad\qquad n,j\geq 1\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>   Since initial values can be easily calculated from (4) we get the following table for $b_{n,j}$
>
> \begin{array}{c|cccccc}
> n\setminus k&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
> \hline
> 1&1\\
> 2&1&1\\
> 3&-1&3&1\\
> 4&2&-1&6&1\\
> 5&-6&0&5&10&1\\
> 6&24&4&-15&25&15&1\\
> \end{array}

**Note:** These values can be found in OEIS as *[A008296](http://oeis.org/A008296)*. They are called *Lehmer-Comtet* numbers and were stored in the archive by N.J.A.Sloane by referring precisely to the example we can see here.

> **Taylor series (part two):**
>
> We are now ready to expand (3) further and obtain using (4)
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x+t)&=(x+t)^{x+t}\\
> &=x^x\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{\left(t\ln(x)\right)^i}{i!}\right)
> \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\left(1+\frac{t}{x}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{t}{x}\right)\right)^j}{j!}x^j\right)\\
> &=x^x\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{\left(t\ln(x)\right)^i}{i!}\right)
> \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=j}^\infty b_{k,j}\frac{\left(\frac{t}{x}\right)^k}{k!}x^j\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=x^x\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{\left(t\ln(x)\right)^i}{i!}\right)
> \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^k b_{k,j}x^j\frac{\left(\frac{t}{x}\right)^k}{k!}\right)\tag{7}\\
> &=x^x\sum_{l=0}^\infty\left( \sum_{{i+k=l}\atop{i,k\geq 0}}\frac{\left(\ln(x)\right)^i}{i!}\cdot\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^kb_{k,j}x^{j-k}\right)t^l\tag{8}\\
> &=x^x\sum_{l=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=0}^l\binom{l}{i}\left(\ln(x)\right)^i\sum_{j=0}^{l-i}b_{l-i,j}x^{j-l+i}\right)\frac{t^l}{l!}\tag{9}\\
> &=x^x\sum_{l=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=0}^l\binom{l}{i}\left(\ln(x)\right)^i\sum_{j=0}^{l-i}b_{l-i,l-i-j}x^{-j}\right)\frac{t^l}{l!}\tag{10}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (6) we use the representation (4).
- In (7) we exchange in the right hand double series the indices $k$ and $j$ respecting $0\leq j\leq k<\infty$.
- In (8) we introduce the index $l$ to collect the terms according to powers of $t$.
- In (9) we write the series in $t$ as exponential generating series by introducing $\binom{l}{i}$.
- In (10) we exchange the order of the elements of the rightmost sum by letting $j\rightarrow l-i-j$.

> **$n$-th derivative of $x^x$:**
>
> Now it's time to harvest. We obtain the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)=x^x$ from (2) and (10).
>
> The $n$-th derivative of $x^x$ is
>
> \begin{align*}
> D_x^n x^x=x^x\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(\ln(x))^i\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}b_{n-i,n-i-j}x^{-j}\tag{11}
> \end{align*}
>   with $b_{n,j}$ the *Lehmer-Comtet* numbers given in (5).

**Example: $n=2$**

Let's look at a small example. Letting $n=2$ we obtain from (11) and the table with $b_{n,j}$:
\begin{align*}
D_x^2x^x&=x^x\sum_{i=0}^2\binom{2}{i}(\ln(x))^i\sum_{j=0}^{2-i}b_{2-i,2-i-j}x^{-j}\\
&=x^x\left(\binom{2}{0}\sum_{j=0}^2b_{2,2-j}x^{-j}+\binom{2}{1}\ln(x)\sum_{j=0}^1b_{1,1-j}x^{-j}\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\left.+\binom{2}{2}\left(\ln(x)\right)^2\sum_{j=0}^0b_{0,0-j}x^{-j}\right)\\
&=x^x\left(\left(b_{2,2}+b_{2,1}\frac{1}{x}+b_{2,0}\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+2\ln(x)\left(b_{1,1}+b_{1,0}\frac{1}{x}\right)
+(\ln(x))^2b_{0,0}\right)\\
&=x^x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+2\ln(x)+\left(\ln(x)\right)^2\right)
\end{align*} 
in accordance with the result of Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 0):

An answer is
\begin{equation}\label{power-exp-deriv-eq}
(x^x)^{(n)}=n!x^{x-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\Biggl[\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} \frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!} \binom{j}{n-k-q}\Biggr]\frac{(\ln x)^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}.
\end{equation}
Click the site https://mathoverflow.net/a/439188 or read the paper

Jian Cao, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, *Closed-form formulas for the $n$th derivative of the power-exponential function $x^x$*, Symmetry **15** (2023), no. 2, Article 323, 13 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15020323.