# General form of the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $x^x$

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, exponential-function, analytic-continuation

Can someone help me to confirm this identity that I have established, I really have no idea how I would go about proving that this is true.

By the way, this is not a homework assignment, I am just genuinely curious. Thank you!

If $f(x)=x^x$, then

$$f^{(n+1)}(x)=f^{(n)}(x)(\ln(x)+1)+\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}\frac{n!}{k(n-k)!}f^{(n-k)}(x)$$
$$\text{ for } n\in\mathbb{N}$$

where $f^{(n)}(x)$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $f(x)$

Comment: The first idea that comes to mind is a proof by [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction): otherwise you can try a "brute force" approach by using [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faà_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258332/nth-derivative-of-xx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n = 1$,

$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= x^x\\
& = e^{x\ln x}\\
f'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} e^{x\ln x}\\
&= e^{x\ln x} \left(\ln x + 1\right)\\
&= x^x\left(\ln x + 1\right)\\
\end{align*}$$

Let $g(x) = \ln x + 1$. Then for $k \ge 1$,
$$g^{(k)}(x) = (-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!\ x^{-k}$$

From the second derivative onwards, i.e. $n \ge 1$, using the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule),

$$\begin{align*}
f^{(n+1)}(x) &= \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f'(x)\\
&= \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[f(x)\ g(x)\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\ f^{(n-k)}(x)\ g^{(n)}(x)\\
&= f^{(n)}(x)\ g^{(0)}(x) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\ f^{(n-k)}(x)\ g^{(n)}(x)\\
&= f^{(n)}(x) \left(\ln x + 1\right) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\ f^{(n-k)}(x)\left[(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!\ x^{-k}\right]\\
&= f^{(n)}(x) \left(\ln x + 1\right) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{n!}{k(n-k)!}\ f^{(n-k)}(x)\ \color{red}{x^{-k}}\\
\end{align*}$$

The red $x^{-k}$ is what I think the question may be missing, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You are right! When I originally did this on paper, I did include an x^k in the denominator. I simply forgot to insert it into my question when I typed it.

Comment: Oh yeah there we go! I like it.

Comment: Also in the last two lines, your n seems to have changed to a Zero

Comment: @Brothersquid fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found something related. Given that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous and $n$-times differentiable on some interval $I\subseteq \Bbb R$, and $u(x)=f(x)g(x)$, then
$$u^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}f^{(n-k)}(x)g^{(k)}(x).$$

If you can find $n$-times differentiable $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $x^x=f(x)g(x)$, then you have your theorem.

Comment: I thought of that, though be careful that the fraction inside the summation has denominator $k$, not $k!$. Wikipedia call this the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule).

Comment: @peterwhy what fraction in the summation?

Comment: That $k$ in the $\frac{n!}{k(n-k)!}$ in the question. But after I worked out my answer, that $k$ instead of $k!$ actually makes sense.

Comment: @peterwhy I didn't catch that. But I'm sure that the method that I suggested would yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In Theorem 3 of the paper [1] below, it was obtained that
\begin{multline}\label{x-poer-x-thm3-driv}\tag{QEq}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}\bigl[(1+x)^{t(1+x)}\bigr]
=n!(1+x)^{t(1+x)-n}\\
\times\sum_{k=0}^{n}t^k(1+x)^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \Biggl[\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} \frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!} \binom{j}{n-k-q}\Biggr] \frac{[\ln(1+x)]^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}.
\end{multline}
Replacing $1+x$ by $x$ in \eqref{x-poer-x-thm3-driv} yields
\begin{equation}\label{x-poer-x-thm3-driv-repl}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}\bigl(x^{tx}\bigr)
=n!x^{tx-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}t^kx^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \Biggl[\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} \frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!} \binom{j}{n-k-q}\Biggr] \frac{(\ln x)^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}.
\end{equation}
See also related comments on the answer at the web site https://mathoverflow.net/a/439188.

Reference

1. Jian Cao, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, *Closed-form formulas for the $n$th derivative of the power-exponential function $x^x$*, Symmetry **15** (2023), no. 2, Article 323, 13 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15020323.