# Inverting a non-analytic exponential

Tags: inverse-function

I've been recently interested in the [nth derivative of $x^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258332/nth-derivative-of-xx), and I jumped to pondering of the inverse of not this function, (because it's known to be $e^{\operatorname{W}\left(\ln x\right)}$, for $\operatorname{W}\left(x\right)$ being the [Lambert W Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)) but rather a more generalized one: $x^{x+k}$. I would look towards using the [Lagrange Inversion Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), but this function is non-analytic. Maybe we could use $(x+k)^{(x+k)}$, but nonetheless, I'm stuck. [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28ax%2Bb%29%5E%28cx%2Bd%29+for+x) gives way too much data in terms of solving $\left(ax+b\right)^{\left(cx+d\right)}=0$, and asking [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+%28ax%2Bb%29%5E%28cx%2Bd%29) to invert the function doesn't exactly work, either.
Thanks!

Comment: $\left(ax+b\right)^{\left(cx+d\right)}=0$ only if $ax+b = 0$.  I did not say also "if" because of complications like $0^0 = 1$ and $0^{-1}$ is undefined, and so on.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666233/solution-for-x-of-y-abxx/4666453#4666453) inverts $(a+bx)^x$