# Solution for $x$ of $\,y=(a+bx)^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, approximation, approximation-theory

> Solution for $x$ of $\,y=(a+bx)^x$

Is there an algebraic solution for $x$ to this equation? I've tried using the Lambert $W$ function and approximating it, but I've had no luck with that. Even an approximation of the solution would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Solve for $x$? What you have written is a function

Comment: yes sorry, i am trying to solve for x, ill edit the post to make that more clear.

Comment: The inverse function  $x(y)$ of the function $y(x)=(a+bx)^x$ cannot be expressed with the standard Lambert-W function in general (as far as I know). This would require a new special function i.e. a "Generalised Lambert function" which is not standardized presently.  Use numerical calculus to solve this equation for $x$.

Answer (score 6):

With [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) where $a,b,c,z$ can be complex:

$$(a+b z)^z=c\iff y\ln(a+b y)=\ln(c)+2\pi i m\implies z_m=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln(c)+2\pi i m)^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\ln^{-n}(a+bx)\right|_{x=0},m\in\Bbb Z$$

Its [summation identity](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/) is tedious to adjust for the Lagrange reversion solution to work. However, there is a [Stirling S1 $S_n^{(m)}$](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/) pattern.

$$\left.\frac{d^r}{dx^r}\ln^{-n}(a+bx)\right|_{x=0}=-\frac{S_r^{(1)}nb^r\ln^{-n-1}(a)}{a^r}+\frac{S_r^{(2)}(n+1)nb^r\ln^{-n-2}(a)}{a^r}-\frac{S_r^{(3)}(n+2)(n+1)nb^r\ln^{-n-3}(a)}{a^r}+\frac{S_r^{(4)}(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)n\ln^{-n-4}(a)b^r}{a^r}+\dots$$

Therefore a solution uses the [pochhammer symbol $(u)_v$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pochhammer%28n%2Ck%29):

$$\boxed{(a+b z)^z=c\implies z_m=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k S_{n-1}^{(k)}(n)_k(\ln(c)+2\pi i m)^n}{n!\ln^{n+k}(a)}\left(\frac ba\right)^{n-1},m\in\Bbb Z}$$

[**shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28-8.2%2B0.2i%29%2B%28-0.4-i%29+x%29%5Ex%2Cx%3Dsum%5Bsum%5B%28ln%280.3-0.6+i%29-4+pi+i%29%5En%2Fn%21+%28%28-0.4-i%29%2F%28-8.2%2B0.2+i%29%29%5E%28n-1%29+%28-1%29%5Ek+stirlings1%28n-1%2Ck%29+%CE%93%28k+%2B+n%29%2F%CE%93%28n%29+ln%28-8.2%2B0.2+i%29%5E%28-n-k%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C100%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D). If both sums are $\infty$, then they are interchangeable and if $a,b\in\Bbb R$, then $\bar z$ is a solution with $2\pi i m,\pm m\in\Bbb N$ corresponding to solutions $z$ with $2\pi i m,\mp m\in\Bbb N$. Finally, for smaller $|b|,|c|$ and larger $|a|$, $|m|$ can be larger with the sum converging to the correct root; usually only $m=0,\pm 1$ works for $|a|\approx |b|\approx |c|$.

It is easier to construct a series solution for the real root if wanted.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is for real $a,b,x,y$. Ask if you want complex values.

$$(a+bx)^x=y$$
$$a+bx=y^\frac{1}{x}$$
$$a+bx=e^\frac{\ln(y)}{x}$$

This equation is an algebraic equation over the complex numbers in dependence of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($x,e^\frac{\ln(y)}{x}$). We don't know therefore how we can rearrange the equation for $x$ by only [elementary functions/operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

We want to look for applicability of Lambert W by presenting the equation in dependence of a variable $t$ and $e^t$.

$$\ln(a+bx)=\frac{\ln(y)}{x}$$
$x\to\frac{e^t-a}{b}$:
$$t=\frac{b\ln(y)}{e^t-a}$$
$$e^t=\frac{at+b\ln(y)}{t}$$
$$\frac{t}{at+b\ln(y)}e^t=1$$
$$\frac{t}{t+\frac{b}{a}\ln(y)}e^t=a$$

We see, this equation cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W, but in terms of Generalized Lambert W:

$$\frac{t}{t-(-\frac{b}{a}\ln(y))}e^t=a$$
$$t=W\left(^{\ \ \ \ \ \ 0}_{-\frac{b}{a}\ln(y)};a\right)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{b}e^{W\left(^{\ \ \ \ \ \ 0}_{-\frac{b}{a}\ln(y)};a\right)}-\frac{a}{b}$$

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $x$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)